# CodeIgniter Ajax CSRF Jquery Cookie Method behaving unexpectedly

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, csrf

**Javascript Section:**

```
var token = $.cookie("csrf_cookie_name");
var tx = document.getElementById("tx"+working_row).value;
var mods =document.getElementById("mods"+working_row).value;
var pos = document.getElementById("pos"+working_row).value;
var startdate = document.getElementById("startdate"+working_row).value;
var enddate = document.getElementById("enddate"+working_row).value;
var fordx = document.getElementById("4dx"+working_row).value;
var qty = document.getElementById("qty"+working_row).value;
var price = document.getElementById("price"+working_row).value;
obj = new Object();
obj={'csrf_token_name':token,'tx':tx,'mods':mods,'pos':pos,'startdate':startdate,'enddate':enddate,'fordx':fordx,'qty':qty,'price':price};
alert(obj.csrf_token_name);
$.post("index.php/auth/fee_schedule",obj, function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

The issue I'm having is that the token variable isn't being included in the post. I'm not sure why. The Alert is [Object Object] so, null. The header of the page has the following:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Medata Preauthorzation System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.sexy-combo.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="icon" type="image" href="/medata/favicon.ico">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.impromptu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/cookie.js"></script>
</head>
```

So the Library and Cookie Functions are included. I use the cookie function 10 other times on the same page to do posts and it works fine, but I don't put any of them into objects with other variables, so it's just inline alla

```
$.post("index.php/auth/tx_history/"+tx_code, { csrf_token_name: $.cookie("csrf_cookie_name") }, function(data){
    //alert(data);
        $("#price"+rowid).val(data);
});
```

I'd Love some Suggestions, i've been hitting my head against this code most of the afternoon for non-stop issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
var token = $.cookie("<?php echo $this->config->item("csrf_cookie_name"); ?>");
```

Comment: Checked the Config, that's the accurate name for the cookie item. Double checked by Alerting that..Nice try though =)

Comment: Nope, that's the problem, I have read somewhere of a documented problem that causes the cookie to be named incorrectly. which means all my other posts worked because I'm extracting the data from the URI and not actually posting any data. 

So I've updated my Config file to name the cookie what it's naming it via the glitch, to make it consistant, and I've updated the name of the token, to csrf_token, and Now I'm getting a value from the $cookies function, but the post still isn't working.

Comment: Scratch that, Just got it to work by changing both the name of the cookie and the name of the element in the cookie to the same thing. Stupid Bug. Thanks for your help!